# Slide down Menu in IOS like Paper app setting

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in IOS development and i am trying to develop a slide down menu like that in "Paper" app 
its looks like a view sliding down and pull another view to locate it at its place in view .
in other words a view that is swapped down and another view appear above it . 
I know this is confusing and I hope the attached images can describe what i want to ask 
i need an advice or a component to help me develop this menu 
Thanking in advance

**the view before sliding the menu**

[image]

**here is the view while sliding**

[image]

**the view after sliding the menu**

[image]

Comment: Asking for a comment is off-topic for stack overflow and answering on how to build this will yield an a to long answer. I suggest you just try and build it yourself and if you get stuck post your code here so we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for this after positioning upper view at -Y axis and changing the Y coordinate of both views as user pans down the lower view. Try and revert back if you get stuck somewhere.

You can follow this tutorial for a quick kickstart: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/dragging-views-with-gestures